# I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module." I added the "type": "module" in the package.json file but I still get another error

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

When I run the following code block, I get the error message "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module." I have already installed node-fetch using

```
npm install node-fetch
```

What could be going wrong here?

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/manishmshiva')
    // Handle success
    .then(response => response.json())  // convert to json
    .then(json => console.log(json))    //print data to console
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err)); // Catch errors
```

I installed node-fetch using

```
npm install node-fetch
```

after which I was expecting the above code to display either the fetched JSON data or a "Request Failed" error, but instead I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" as explained above.

I also get another err0r shown below after including "type": module in the package.json file.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'node-fetch' imported from e:\i_Chile Profile\1_i_CodeLearn\Javascript Projects\Javascript\ProjectNode\src\fetchAPI.js
```

I'm using Visual Studio code.

Comment: Which `node_modules` directory have you installed `node-fetch` to?

Comment: I've now installed node-fetch in the current project directory and its now working. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"type": "module"` into your package.json in this case, because you use the `import` syntax.

Comment: Hi. I added the "type": "module"  in the package.json file but I still get another error. Check it here and tell me what could be going wrong: node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'node-fetch' imported from e:\i_Chile Profile\1_i_CodeLearn\Javascript Projects\Javascript\ProjectNode\src\fetchAPI.js

Comment: Added but not working yet